# wifi problem in Ubuntu 14 in VMWare

Tags: wireless

I start to use Ubuntu 14, and i have a problem with my wifi.
Actually I'm connectibg via Wifi in my laptop, but when i start Ubuntu ( its installed by VMware ), i have internet but its showing like I'm using Ethernet not Wifi.

Comment: So what's the problem exactly? it's a *virtual* machine, and it's using a *virtual* ethernet adapter provided by the host.

Comment: Yes exactly, but when i want to show for example lists of available wireless. I cannot

Comment: Steeldriver, can you help me for that please, because is showing wlan0 : error ........ : no such device

Answer (score 0):

In a virtual environment the guest will always show as ethernet connection even if the host is using wifi that is because the guest does not see the hosts hardware it is contained within the virtual environment.

The only exception to this rule is if you use an usb adapter for wifi then it can been seen by the guest machine.